# How to handle multiple versions of binary file format

Tags: c#, c++, data-structures, versioning, file-formats

I'm writing a reader for the custom binary file format used in one game. The format has multiple versions for example:

```
struct FileHeader
{
   ushort version;
   uint fieldX; // version 1
   uint fieldXX; // added in version 3
   uint fieldY; // version 2
   uint fieldZ; // version 4
}
```

The problem is, different versions can add the new field in between other fields so it's not always added at the end. Otherwise, that would be easy to solve with inheritance.

One solution I can think of is to have different structures for each version of the format like:

```
struct FileHeader001
{
    ushort version;
    uint fieldX;
}

struct FileHeader003
{
    ushort version;
    uint fieldX;
    uint fieldXX;
    uint fieldY;
}
```

But then if I have some functions that operate on FileHeader it doesn't seem possible to use it easily because older versions don't have specific fields. And it's not possible to have 1 function to pass the structures.

Is there any good way to deal with it?

Comment: Are you asking about this for C# or C++?  The answers will be very different.

Comment: the only difference is C# has attributes, other than that it's similar. I don't want to use attributes because of performance.

Comment: Hiding all of this with inheritance is the simpler part; a key piece of what you seem to be asking about is how much code/definition to share between the implementations, and that really has to be considered in context of the application specific question of the degree to which the versions are more alike, or more different.  Not infrequently this means that you have a tree of possibilities - some implementations which are completely unique, others than handle a range of related versions with a lot of common code but support for slight differences.

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, you have to open the stream and read enough bytes to determine which file format you are actually dealing with first.  This solution is not unlike what many graphics tools do to discover the file format of an image before actually using the right library to read the data.

In this case the work would be similar to this process:

- Read file identifier if present (for example Java classes start with the constant 0xCAFEBABE and some Unicode files start with a Byte Order Marking)
- Read the version number (which is always a `ushort` in this example)
- Determine which header you need
- Roll back the stream
- Deserialize to the appropriate structure

If you can make it work with inheritance, awesome.  However, not all problems are solved that way.

Comment: but if I have a function that takes FileHeader as a parameter then I can't pass there all of the structures. I need 1 struct for that

Comment: You'll have to design how you handle that appropriately.  You could have a function to determine the structure, and rewind the stream similar to what I described above, and then pass the stream and the structure to the method.  That's just one way to handle it.

Comment: You should differentiate between a file header structure/object that you pass around in your code and the binary representation of the header in different versions of the file format. Ideally, your header object would have methods to read from and write to a stream, and those would scan the data with appropriate conditional code depending on the version. Just don't pass the memory address of this structure to read() or write() calls.

Answer (score 1):

Universal solution is to always have the most recent version of the structure and use `BinaryReader`.

```
struct FileHeader
{
   ushort version;
   uint fieldX; // version 1
   uint fieldXX; // added in version 3
   uint fieldY; // version 2
   uint fieldZ; // version 4
}

FileHeader ReadFile(string path)
// this won't work if newer version removes some field
{
    using (BinaryReader b = new BinaryReader(File.Open(path, FileMode.Open)))
    {
       var fileHeader = new FileHeader();
       var version = b.ReadUInt16();
       fileHeader.version = version;
       fileHeader.fieldX = b.ReadUInt32();
       if (version >= 3)
           fileHeader.fieldXX = b.ReadUInt32();
       if (version >= 2)
           fieldHeader.fieldY = b.ReadUInt32();
       if (version >= 4)
           fieldHeader.fieldZ = b.ReadUInt32();

       return fileHeader;
    }
}
```

You can also introduce `[Version]` attribute but that can be slow if you call function using reflection frequently. But that way you can also create a generic read function like `ReadStruct<T>`.

```
struct FileHeader
{
   ushort version;
   [Version(Min = 1)]
   uint fieldX; // version 1
   [Version(Min = 3)]
   uint fieldXX; // added in version 3
   [Version(Min = 2)]
   uint fieldY; // version 2
   [Version(Min = 4)]
   uint fieldZ; // version 4
}
```

If you're sure that new versions always append new fields at the end, you can solve it with inheritance too.

Other than that I recommend this article: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25896/Reading-Unmanaged-Data-Into-Structures

With some crazily performant unsafe function:

```
public static T ToStruct<T>(this byte[] buffer)
    where T : unmanaged
{
    try {
        unsafe {
            fixed (byte* ptr = &buffer[0]) {
                return *(T*)ptr;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SystemException ex)
    {
        throw new TypeLoadException($"Could not convert the buffer into type {type.Name}", ex);
    }
}
```

but that will not work if you want to support multiple versions.

Comment: When you do binary marshalling as in the latter code, you must be carefull with inheritance since it can messup the order of the fields.

Comment: About the `ReadFile` way of doing this. To overcome the remove filed limitation one might use an `if(2 <= version && version < 5) { // read deleted field }`.  But if we take a step back we realize that in that case we encode the different versions scattered along the read function. In my opinion it would look more clear to define different structures for different versions.